# Get List Workflow internal status for all lists/items in site

Tags: 2013, workflow, rest, jsom

We have workflows running on several different lists in a site. Occasionally an item will suspend due to either something wrong with our farm (I'm not a central admin just a site collection admin) or an unhandled/unhandleable error with the workflow. As best I can tell there is no way to see suspended list workflows easily -- I have to go to each item in the list (hundereds), click the ellipsis, workflows, and see if they are suspended.

I'd like to find a javascript (REST preferred but also JSOM) that can check all the list workflows. I've googled and found a lot of tutorials on how to start a workflow using REST.

I've also found a lot of tutorials on how to read the Status column, but that is not updated when workflow is terminated or suspended. So that can't help me. I need to be able to read the **internal status**.

I found this REST endpoint (POST).

```
_api/SP.WorkflowServices.WorkflowInstanceService.Current/EnumerateInstancesForSite()
```

And that seems to work for the site workflows, but I can't find any documentation for how to get the instance for a list item.

I found [this msdn documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/EN-US/library/microsoft.sharepoint.workflowservices.workflowinstanceservice_methods.aspx) which has methods like `Enumerate(WorkflowSubscription)` or `EnumerateInstancesForListItem(ListGuid,ItemId)`. But those don't seem to be available from REST.

I have used the following endpoint to see the workflows that are enabled on my list.

```
_api/SP.WorkflowServices.WorkflowSubscriptionService.Current/EnumerateSubscriptionsByList('guid in here')
```

I get Id, DefinitionId, and EventSourceId. I assume Id is the one I want and then I tried

```
/_api/SP.WorkflowServices.WorkflowInstanceService.Current/Enumerate('guid in here')
```

But that returned **The method Enumerate cannot be invoked as its parameter parentSubscription is not supported.** I also tried the other guids with the same results.

Anybody know how to do this? Will I have to do it with JSOM? If so can you recommend documentation for that?

**EDIT**

SP 2013 on prem

Answer (score 2):

I believe you would have already found a solution for this by now. But these methods work if you use use the following syntax

```
EnumerateInstancesForListItem(listId='<replace with list id e.g. 958ed475-55a1-4c23-86e7-fae1499863a0>',itemId='<replace with item id e.g. 1>')
```

For example :

```
_api/SP.WorkflowServices.WorkflowInstanceService.Current/EnumerateInstancesForListItem(listId='958ed475-55a1-4c23-86e7-fae1499863a0',itemId='1')
‍
```